# Best way to use custom Roles with Active Directory login

Tags: c#, active-directory, roles

I looking for the best solution to my problem, what we are wanting to do is use active directory for our base login so we don't have to manage passwords ect. But instead of using AD groups we are wanting to create custom roles.  So I might have one role that will equal 5 different AD groups.

What I am thinking of doing is dumping all users in a specific group via c# to a custom user table that links to a roleid to userid table. Anyone have any thoughts on this? But I also need to manage the custom user table in a way if someone gets removed from one of these groups then they need to loose access, not sure how to handle that one.

Currently my method looks something like this:

```
        using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "SETON"))
        {
            //Gets all Users in a AD Group
            using (GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, groupName))
            {
                //Mkae sure group is not null
                if (grp != null)
                {
                    foreach (Principal p in grp.GetMembers())
                    {
                        //Sets up Variables to enter into Finance User Table
                        string UserName = p.SamAccountName;
                        string DisplayName = p.Name;
                        string emailAddress = p.UserPrincipalName;

                        //Get users detials by user
                        using (UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, UserName))
                        {
                            if (userPrincipal != null)
                            {                                    
                                //Test to see if user is in AD Group
                                bool inRole = userPrincipal.IsMemberOf(grp);
                                if (inRole)
                                {
                                    //Test to See if UserName already exists in Finance User Table
                                    var ds = User.GetUserList(UserName);

                                    //If don't exist add them and to the new Role
                                    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
                                    {
                                        //Add User to FinanceUSer Table
                                        Seton.Roster.User user = new User();
                                        user.UserName = UserName;
                                        user.Name = DisplayName;                                            
                                        int id = user.Save();

                                        //Get RoleID by RoleName with Method
                                        var roleDS = SecurityRole.GetRoleList(roleName);
                                        if (roleDS.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                                        {
                                            var roleDR = roleDS.Tables[0].Rows[0];
                                            int roleid = Convert.ToInt32(roleDR["roleid"].ToString());
                                            SecurityRoleUserLink.AddNewLink(roleid, id);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    //if they exist just Get thier userid and add them to new Role
                                    else
                                    {
                                        //Get UserID of existing FinanceUser
                                        var userDR = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];
                                        int id = Convert.ToInt32(userDR["userid"].ToString());

                                        //Get RoleID by RoleName with Method
                                        var roleDS = SecurityRole.GetRoleList(roleName);
                                        if (roleDS.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                                        {
                                            var roleDR = roleDS.Tables[0].Rows[0];
                                            int roleid = Convert.ToInt32(roleDR["roleid"].ToString());

                                            //Test to see if user already in this role
                                            if(!SecurityRoleUserLink.UserInRole(id,roleid))
                                                SecurityRoleUserLink.AddNewLink(roleid, id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are reinventing the wheel. Look at products like [MS Windows Authorisation Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897401.aspx) (AzMan), or it's [open-source equivalent](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=azman%20open%20source&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFcQFjAA&url=http://netsqlazman.codeplex.com/&ei=BiIAUJDQJOiy0QXfkYmXBw&usg=AFQjCNELE8xs1lKYccO3IqsB5giHzHxLtg).

These allow you to define "Operations" (i.e. tasks that a user can perform), and map those operations to AD groups. They will let you do a lot more stuff besides, but at a minimum they certainly meet your needs.

AzMan configuration can be stored in XML, a database, or in AD, so it's very flexible in that regard as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this a couple of ways, but the answer is really about how complex your looking to implement security. Are you doing field level or record level?

1. Cache AD User Accounts and Groups in your application for quick retrieval.

   - Pros - Accounts are in your DB and if AD has issues, you aren't SOL.
   - Cons - Needs to be repopulated and a scheduled basis and can get out of sync
2. Use AD for both user's and Groups with a mapping of Application Groups to Domain Groups.

   - Pros - Letting AD do your work so you don't have to manage it in the application

Of course there are more pros and cons, but, to me, these stand out.

We currently use AzMan and it's not supported - that I know of. It works well for the most part, but there is a lot of back and forth syncing that you have to account for as well as for performance, you still end up caching it in the Application.

You can also find an open source on code plex: [NetSqlAzMan](http://netsqlazman.codeplex.com/) that looks very promising.